# Nesting a List<string> in a custom class List via a LINQ SQL Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my code that retrieves information from the database about a list of Printer Drivers.  The table has a list of Printer Drivers, as well as what servers they were found on.

```
 public List<PrinterDrivers> GetPrinterDriversFromCache()
        {
            using (dbPrintSimpleDataContext db = new dbPrintSimpleDataContext())
            {
                var q = from p in db.GetTable<tblPrinterDriverCache>()
                        where p.CacheGUID == mostRecentCacheID()
                        group p by p.PrinterDriver into g
                        select new PrinterDrivers
                        {
                            DriverName = g.Key,
                            InstalledOn = g.Where(x => x.PrinterDriver == g.Key).Select(x => x.PrinterServer).ToList(),
                            Usable = (g.Count() == Properties.Settings.Default.PrintServers.Count)
                        };
                return q.ToList();
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to return is a List that contains a property that has a List in it that contains what servers that printer driver exists on.  I think that I'm up against the limit of my current LINQ SQL knowledge :(

The resultant List should contain:

DriverName = Printer driver name, in this case the group key (string)

InstalledOn = List (containing the list of servers that this printer driver was found on)

Usable = A simple bool check if the servers that it was found on is the same amount as the servers we have in the preferences file.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you elaborate exact problem you are facing?

Comment: InstalledOn contains spurious results, that is, not results that I was expecting.  I was expecting each grouped DriverName to contain a list of the print servers that it was installed on.  The table in this query contains a list of print drivers and print servers, so, the query should only return the specified print driver along with a list of what servers have been found. Does that make sense? I'm a bit foggy because I've been coding all day

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[LINQ Lambda, Group by with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745904/linq-lambda-group-by-with-list)

The problem is that Linq does not know about `ToList`. Only part of the entire query is executed on the server as there is an extra `ToList` call before the final `ToList` call (Untested code below)

```
public List<PrinterDrivers> GetPrinterDriversFromCache()
    {
        using (dbPrintSimpleDataContext db = new dbPrintSimpleDataContext())
        {
            var q = (from p in db.GetTable<tblPrinterDriverCache>()
                    where p.CacheGUID == mostRecentCacheID()
                    group p by p.PrinterDriver.DriverName into g
                    select g
                    ).ToList().Select(g => new PrinterDrivers
                    {
                        DriverName = g.Key,
                        InstalledOn = g.Where(x => x.PrinterDriver == g.Key).Select(x => x.PrinterServer).ToList(),
                        Usable = (g.Count() == Properties.Settings.Default.PrintServers.Count)
                    });
            return q.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Translating the same pattern from the answer I linked, yours would be:

```
var q = db.GetTable<tblPrinterDriverCache>()
            .Where(p => p.CacheGUID == mostRecentCacheID())
            .Select(o => new { DriverName = o.DriverName, PrintServer = o.PrintServer })
            .GroupBy(g => g.DriverName)
            .ToList()
            .Select(g => new PrinterDrivers
                {
                    DriverName = g.Key,
                    InstalledOn = g.Select(p => p.PrinterServer).ToList(),
                    Usable = (g.Count() == Properties.Settings.Default.PrintServers.Count)
                }
            )
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This makes me feel like maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.  Maybe there's a better way to get this information then trying to make it all happen in the one query.

Comment: Actually, If you are filtering first (you are), then returning the data, it isn't that bad. I can't think of a better way to do it and this should be fine. Any other way (short of something I am not thinking of) is going to have even more (N+1) queries.

Comment: Yeah okay. This code resulted in the same thing happening (I had to add "select g" after the " group p by p.PrinterDriver into g" line so the query would work).  I might check the DB for duplicate data or something like that.